# what the purpose of position:"last" in jqgrid?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have question about jqgrid, what the purpose of position:"last" in jqgrid?

for more details, this is my code :

```
.navButtonAdd("#rowsTransaksi",{
        caption:"",
        buttonicon:"",
        onClickButton:function(){
        var datarow = {acctId: "", currency: "", amount: ""};
        //var su=jQuery("#Transaksi").addRowData(datarow,"last");
        var su=jQuery("#Transaksi").addRowData("X",datarow,"last");
        if(su) { jQuery("#Transaksi").setSelection('X') }
    },  ***position:"last"***
```

Help me please, tell me about explanation for my question.. =)
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [jqGrid documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acustom_buttons).

> position: (“first” or “last”) the position where the button will be added (i.e., before or after the standard buttons).

Comment: Ok...Thanks.But i have one problem about this.If "last" im replace with "first", and then not modified...Why?do you know?=)

Answer (score 1):

There are some more important problem in your code. The line `addRowData("X",datarow,"last")` use always **the same** "X" value as the rowid, but id **must be unique**. I suggest you to use `$.jgrid.randId()` method instead which generate new unique id.

Your code could be rewritten as the following:

```
var myGrid = $("#Transaksi");
myGrid.jqGrid('navButtonAdd', "#pager", {
    caption: "",
    buttonicon: "ui-icon-plus",
    title: "Add empty row",
    onClickButton: function () {
        var datarow = { acctId: "", currency: "", amount: "" },
            newId = $.jgrid.randId();
        if (myGrid.addRowData(newId, datarow, "last")) {
            myGrid.setSelection(newId);
        }
    },
    position:"first"
});
```

which will be place the new button which looks like "+" on the first place (before refresh button on the picture below)

[image]

see [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithAddEmptyRowButton.htm).

Comment: Thank you so much, this is useful to me. But, how i can add empty row at once/ simultaneously with edit row?Please help me about this...=)

Comment: 1 more, what the purpose is "newId = $.jgrid.randId();" ?
after i try, seen error "newId = $.jgrid.randId(); is no function"
=)

Comment: @soccerenz: Probably you use some "retro" version of the jqGrid. The `$.jgrid.randId` exist starting with 4.0.0 and you use probably 3.8.2 or earlier. Look at my demo it has no such problems.

Comment: @soccerenz: The answer on your first question about the row editing you will find [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6939642/properties-inlineedittrue-in-jqgrid/6952678#6952678)

Comment: i've seen my jqgrid version...and it turns out v-3.6, Thanks Mr.Oleg.I can try your command..=)