# Properties "inlineEdit:true" in jqgrid?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, propertygrid

There properties "inlineEdit:true" in jqgrid? 
for example code is :

```
rowNum:10,
        rowList:[10,40,70],
        pager: '#rowsTransaksi',
        sortname: 'depositType',
        viewrecords: true,
        sortorder: "desc",
        caption:"Payee Accounts",
        forceFit : true,
        cellEdit: true,
***inlineEdit:true***
        inlineEdit:true,
        editurl:"noabjad.json",
```

Comment: There are no "inlineEdit:true" property in the jqGrid. It will be just ignored. The `cellEdit: true` only will be used. Do you have local or remote data? What do you want to do?

Comment: i want to select row at grid, and direct inline edit when selected.How can i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use for example the following [onSelectRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods) event handler:

```
onSelectRow: function (rowid) {
    if (rowid !== lastSel) {
        myGrid.jqGrid('saveRow', lastSel);
        lastSel = rowid;
    }
    myGrid.jqGrid('editRow', rowid, true, function(){
        $("input, select", e.target).focus();
    });
}
```

It implements the behavior which are very close to the cell editing, but the whole row will be set in the editing mode. See [the modified version](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithAddAndEditEmptyRowButton.htm) of the demo from your [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6937622/what-the-purpose-of-positionlast-in-jqgrid/6945318#6945318).